# SimpleDateFormat issue on AM / PM

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have the following `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.FRANCE);
Date fullDate = sdf.parse(date + " " + time);
```

Where `date` is `24/01/2017` and `time` is `12:55` (24h format).

But for some reason `Date` recognizes the time as `00:55`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 00:55 is 24h, 12:55 could well be 12h format.

Comment: I have defined the Locale as the French one, didn't I? I am located in France, what would be the best way to handle the Locale?

Comment: @ChristopherK., how do you detect that Date recognizes the time as 00:55?

Comment: Sorry, the Locale is only for the date format symbols "_locale - the locale whose date format symbols should be used_" ... please ignore.

Comment: With the debugger, `fullDate = Tue Jan 24 00:44:00 GMT+01:00 2017`. when 12:44 PM was inputted.

Comment: It seems that in your Question you have `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` but maybe your code has `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` instead ... the 'H' needs to be uppercase, what JDk are you using ? The result you are getting is standard for `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm`

Comment: The debugger uses `toString` so, ..

Comment: @ChristopherK. it seems that your system locale supports am/pm format, that's why you see this. For example I see "Tue Jan 24 12:55:00 YEKT 2017" because I use 24-h format in my system.

Comment: This is somewhat true, I have changed the `Locale` to `Locale.US` and put back the format to HH. You can answer my question so I can accept it :)

Comment: Also write "System.out.println(sdf.format(fullDate));" after parsing and you will get the result using the same formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the locale to US and putting back the following format: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` I have solved my problem.

This is what I have now:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
Date fullDate = sdf.parse(date + " " + time);
```